# Open file with default associated program using Java/C++

Tags: java, c++, file, file-association

I have file, lets call it `document.doc`, and I want to open it with MS Word or some other program (default). What would be solution (in C++ or Java) be?. I prefer Java but I will need C++ later, so I'm asking for both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With C++ should be this: `ShellExecute(0, 0, L"document.doc", 0, 0 , SW_SHOW );`

Java: `java.awt.Desktop.getDesktop().open("document.doc");`

Comment: Does it select necessary program from OS config to open .doc file? I mean, like a cmd window?

Comment: @huseyin tugrul buyukisik. It should check what is default associated program and open with it. If there is no default program it should ask what program to use.

Answer (score 3):

Java:

```
Desktop.getDesktop().open(file);
```

See [`Desktop.open(File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open%28java.io.File%29) for details beyond:

> Launches the associated application to open the file.